# Text visibility depending on screen brightness

Tags: javascript, html, css

Weird question: Is there any way for me to make the visibility of a Text to react according to the screen brightness? It has to be fairly beginner friendly.

Comment: Not sure what you're exactly looking for, are you trying to adjust the text color based on the background brightness?

Comment: I don't think screen brightness is within the reach of any Browser. Even if you adjust and see the numerical data displayed on the screen in "NITS", it's a program integrated into the monitor... not sure the monitor would send settings data to the PC at all except sync.

Comment: I am not sure what is the visibility of a text but detecting screen brightness could be found by body or main page's `l` value of `hsl` which decide color's brightness.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea but. Unfortunately, JavaScript isn't allowed to get such user data for security reasons.

You can get more info on why that is on the following StackOverflow posts.

1. [how to use javascript to measure how bright a users monitor is (by user 'HankV')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883202/how-to-use-javascript-to-measure-how-bright-a-users-monitor-is)
2. [automatically detect how bright a users monitor is (by user 'JasonS')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700990/automatically-detect-how-bright-a-users-monitor-is/3701041#3701041)

That being said.
**(and... Unfortunately, **I doubt** getting it to work **will be beginner-friendly** as you have requested. But I will leave my answer here if you ever wanted to have a try at it in the future.)**

There might be a way you can get it to work. And if you do get it to work. Only use this for learning purposes.

One method I came across was that there **used** to be a method of getting how bright the user's screen's backlight is.

`screenBrightness = window.screen.mozBrightness;`

"it indicates how bright the screen's backlight is, on a scale from 0 (very dim) to 1 (full brightness); this value is a double-precision float."

You can find more info about it here. [on MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/mozBrightness)

A small disclaimer: This feature is deprecated. And is not recommended to use. And most modern browsers might not support it. (Try testing on Firefox)

In [this article](https://reference.codeproject.com/book/dom/screen/mozbrightness), I found out that,
"In order to use `screen.mozBrightness` you have to set the preference `dom.screenBrightnessProperty.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`."

And if you can get the device brightness like this. You can use that data to change the text-visibility.

To add to this. There are many other JavaScript `Screen` API properties you can utilize in future projects. `screen.colorDepth`for example. You can find a list of them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen).

Comment: Thx, but most of the stuff was to complicated to implement